# Server Side rendering in Nuxt Axios module proxy URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

I'm using Axios module officially provided by Nuxt.js here, [https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module](http://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module.).

How can I call action "SET_NEW_DEAL" from component in fetch method?

```
async fetch ({ store }) {
   await store.dispatch('SET_NEW_DEAL',store.getters.newDeal.page);
}
```

Is this correct?

Mine Acions file api request as below:

```
export default {
      async SET_NEW_DEAL ({commit}, payload) {

      return this.$axios.$get(`/api/?page=${payload}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
          commit('SET_NEW_DEAL',response.data);
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })

    }
}
```

Not able to hit api request, thus not able to commit mutation and so on.

I'm using proxy url configuration in `nuxt.config.js` also.

Comment: After few Days i got my mistake.New Acions file api request as below:
    export default {
          async SET_NEW_DEAL ({commit}, payload) {
          await this.$axios.$get(`/api/?page=${payload}`)
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
              commit('SET_NEW_DEAL',response.data);
            }
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })
        }
    }
Now it will wait for api reponse than go for commit